# Invalid JSON string error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm on Rails 2.3.5. In a typical user controller create action

```
class UsersController
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    respond_to do |format]
      if @user.save ...
      else
        format.json ....
      end        
  end
end
```

When a client passes an invalid / malformed JSON string for input, Rails throw a 500 internal server error saying "Invalid JSON string". Is it possible for me to trap the error so I can give a custom message?

**UPDATED** Here's the stacktrace as requested. Just so I'm clear, I know this is a malformed JSON string, my question is not how to fix the JSON string but rather how to trap this particular error so I can send back a more meaningful error message than HTTP 500 Internal Server Error. Thanks in advance for your help

```
Error occurred while parsing request parameters.
Contents:

user: {login: "John", email: "john@yahoo.com", password: "111"}}
/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Mon Nov 08 02:01:04 -0800 2010

  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  Invalid JSON string
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/json/backends/yaml.rb:14:in `decode'
    c:1:in `__send__'
    c:1:in `decode'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:42:in `parse_formatted_parameters'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:11:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:93:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:114:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:34:in `run'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:108:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/rack/static.rb:31:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:46:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in `each'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in `call'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
    ...
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:34:in `run'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:111
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    script/server:3
re.rb:31:in `require'
    script/server:3
```

Comment: can you put a complete backtrace, please ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found this rails plugin to work on rails 3.0.5: https://github.com/kares/request_exception_handler

As Rob Cameron
 suggests it loads your rails application and raises the parseError from your application code. I haven't tested it's performance impact, but it does seem to work well.

Answer (score 0):

Looking in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/json/backends/yaml.rb (admittedly a slightly different version), it looks like a ParseError is being raised. Assuming the error is occurring at "format.json", you could try something like

```
begin
  format.json
rescue ParseError => e
  render :text => "Now there's some ugly JSON! (#{e.message})", :status => 500
end
```

If that doesn't work, you can try to catch it earlier using the rescue_from callback in your controller.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
...
  rescue_from ParseError do |e|
    render ...
  end
...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately the error isn't raised at format.json. I believe it's raised before the user/create action is called because Rails needs to parse the JSON string to get access to params.

Comment: Ah, I guess that makes sense. In that case, try the rescue_from callback. I've added an example up above.

Comment: Another good idea but alas, no dice, the error is raised before it even hits the controller

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same issue right now -- I have an API that someone could pass invalid JSON to and I want to be smart about the error I return. I'm running Rails 3.0.5. I traced the error being thrown to `lib/active_support/json/backends/yaml.rb` line 17:

```
def decode(json)
  if json.respond_to?(:read)
    json = json.read
  end
  YAML.load(convert_json_to_yaml(json))
rescue ArgumentError
  raise ParseError, "Invalid JSON string"
end
```

So, `json.read` fails and throws the error. Unfortunately this happens long before your controller is ever invoked (it's part of the initial request params parsing where Rails ties into Rack). I would think that in order to catch this you would need to add a little monkey-patching to overwrite some of the built-in error throwing and instead bubble up something you can use...maybe you could add a header to the request object that you could then detect in your controller and throw your own error.

Unfortunately I don't think this will work for me since I only want to override the behavior when accessing the API, not the rest of the site. Although I suppose in the monkey-patch, assuming I have access to the request object, I could tell it to only use my new behavior if the requested path matches a regex like `/\/api\//`

Comment: I have solved this problem using Rack middleware. The middleware is inserted before ActionDispatch::ParamsParser and catches the errors emitted by @app.call. Since controller actions are also rack apps in rails applications, I can use a controller action to render a pretty error message using all of rails templating. (Posting for other folk who get here from Google) https://gist.github.com/4709748